# Take advantage of ListBox multicolumn property

Tags: c#, listbox

Is possible to take advantage of MultiColumn property when Items collections are managed by a DataSource? (Use of DataBound items).

I want to try the following snippet :

```
this.listBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
            "Item 1, column 1",
            "Item 2, column 1",
            "Item 3, column 1",
            "Item 4, column 1",
            "Item 5, column 1",
            "Item 1, column 2",
            "Item 2, column 2",
            "Item 3, column 2"});
        this.listBox1.MultiColumn = true;
```

Im using C# 3.5

Thanks

Comment: just 9 rows, is not a complex binding

Answer (score 2):

I think you could try with a listview, just switch it to detail view and try something like:

```
    foreach (row r in collection)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
        item.Text = r.field1; //this will be col1
        item.SubItems.Add(r.field2); //col2 
        item.SubItems.Add(r.field3); //col3
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
    }
```

hope it helps

Comment: this will work if datasource property is enable? using datasets